# activities set in code tags TWIG?

Tags: twig

I have the following code :

```
{% set foo = "'apple', 'orange', 'citrus'" %}
{% set bar =[foo] %}
{% for i in 0..3 %}
{{ cycle(bar[0], i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

output ( 'apple', 'orange', 'citrus' 'apple', 'orange', 'citrus' 'apple', 'orange', 'citrus' 'apple', 'orange', 'citrus' )

and

```
{% set bar = ['apple', 'orange', 'citrus'] %}
{% for i in 0..3 %}
{{ cycle(bar, i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

output ( apple orange citrus apple )

I want to ask is :

how to code below :

```
{% set foo = "'apple', 'orange', 'citrus'" %}
{% set bar =[foo] %}
{% for i in 0..3 %}
{{ cycle(bar[0], i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

operation and returns the contents as this code :

```
{% set bar = ['apple', 'orange', 'citrus'] %}
{% for i in 0..3 %}
{{ cycle(bar, i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

please help me solve it.tkanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to split your string then cycle on it:

```
{% set foo = "'apple','orange','citrus'" %}
{% set bar = [foo | split(',')] %}
{% for i in 0..3 %}
   {{ cycle(bar[0], i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

as you know by putting the split result in bracket it will be two dimensional array then you can get first index of the new array.